# node js (with ejs view engine) give undefined variable on the view

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pug, ejs

I've been working on this for a few hours now but still can't get anywhere. I have a view that tries to create a geojson file on the fly and return it to the node view as a variable. The variable is not empty before it hits the res.render line but when it the view gets loaded, the result is always undefined.

```
app.get('mymap', function(req, res, next){
    var featureCollection= {
            type : 'FeatureCollection',
            features : new Array()
        };

    Shapes.find({'id' : 778899}, function(err, data){
            data.forEach(function(d){
                collection.features.push(d);
            });
            res.render('mymap.ejs', { geojson: featureCollection});
        });
});
```

this is where i call to see if there's something on the view

```
 var mymap = '<%- geojson%>';
  alert('Current values ' + mymap.type);
```

Not really sure what's wrong.. I even tried to just make up a variable with multiple properties, eg:

```
var test = { place: 'Here and There', size : 5555 }
res.render ('mymap.ejs', { geojson: test });
```

Still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you had a typo in your code:

```
var mymap = '<%- geojson%>';
```

It should be:

```
var mymap = '<%= geojson %>';
```

More precisely, if you want to read a Javascript Object from server-side, I suggest to pass it as a JSON string:

```
var mymap = JSON.parse('<%= JSON.stringify(geojson) %>');
```